# symfony2 routing, bad parsing

Tags: php, symfony

I have an application in symfony2, and i create routing like this:

```
spec_add:
    path:     /add.html
    defaults: { _controller: MyBundle:Spec:add }
    methods:  [GET, POST]

spec_add_to_order:
    path:     /{indent}/add.html
    defaults: { _controller:  MyBundle:Spec:add }
    methods:  [GET, POST]
    requirements:
      indent: \d+

spec_edit:
    path:     /{id}/edit.html
    defaults: { _controller: MyBundle:Spec:add }
    methods:  [GET, POST]
    requirements:
      id: \d+
```

And I have controller **SpecController** and method:

```
public function addAction(Indent $indent = null,Specification $specification = null, Request $request)
```

when I go to address *mydomain.dev/{myindentId}/add.html*

i get indent object but I get Specification object too, Why? i don't want specification in this case what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If Specification is an entity, as far as I know, the closest you can do is to add a default value for your entity $specification : { _controller:  MyBundle:Spec:add, specification: 0 }. If you pass null, $specification will be instantiate with new Specification($indent). With 0 the constructor method will return null. It's a workaround I used, so someone could have a better idea.

Comment: I tried but still have Specification object not empty

Comment: You need `unique` prefix for example or something of sort in order for the `Routing` component to distinguish between routes. Right now `{id`} and `{indent}` are having a `\d+` requirement and the first route to match that is executed - in your case that would be `spec_add_to_order`. So basically there's no way for you to open `spec_edit` with your current configuration.